# CDI @Produces doesn't return value from jsf

Tags: jsf, cdi, weld

I tried to add @Produces to my variables in my backingbean like this:

```
@Produces   
@Named  
String selectedCustomerFirstname;
```

and removed the getters and setters. In my xhtml page I show the value like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{selectedCustomerFirstname}" ></p:inputText>
```

The problem now is that the value gets displayed correctly, but if I change it and submit the form, the backingbean always receives the old value... Does ayone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: `@Produces` only outjects the value, you can't manipulate an immutable entity (like String) in this way, AFAIK.

Comment: Why don't you use a @Named bean of some scope with a simple field for that? 
BTW, getter/setters are a good thing here )